# NANT: Style task passing parameter to xslt

Tags: nant

I have a problem with passing arguments from the NAnt style task to a xslt sheet.
This is my NAnt code snippet. The properties path and file are definetly set.

```
<style style="${xslt.file}" extension="xml" in="${xml.file}" destdir=".">
    <parameters>
         <parameter name="path" value="${path}" 
                    namespaceuri="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" />
         <parameter name="doc" value="${file}" 
                    namespaceuri="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" />
    </parameters>
</style>
```

My Parameter are declared as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<xsl:param name="path"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="file" />
```

And accessed by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$path" />
<xsl:value-of select="$file" />
```

But when the file is transformed, $path and $file are both empty. I have tried with and without the namespaceuri of the style task. 
What I am doing wrong?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: doesnt' work with xsltproc eiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, why do you set $file and use $doc ?

BTW, here is a working example:

```
<style style="web.config.xsl" in="web.config.xsl" out="web.config">
 <parameters>
  <parameter name="OSVersion" value="${OSVersion}"/>
 </parameters>
</style>
```

and the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:param name="OSVersion"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$OSVersion"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried it another time with having minor changes to my code. I initialized the '<xsl:param name="path">PATH</xsl:param>' and it works. No idea why, but your are the only one who has answered my question you get the accepted mark :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the phenomenon Dennis described in his comment on the first answer. It seems that NAnt only executes the XSLT again if it has changed and doesn't notice that you have changed the parameters for the `<style>` element. Hence, once you have added your `<parameter>` elements to your NAnt file, running NAnt will not cause the XSLT to run with the new parameter values unless you have changed the XSLT file itself.